# Can map points be entered in Postgis by clicking on the map in QGIS?

Tags: postgis, qgis

I have a Postgis table of about 200 entries for which I have to enter lat/lon coordinates. I use QGIS to process and display them. Is there a way of clicking at the QGIS map and thereby entering the coordinates into the Postgis table?

I can find the coordinates on the map, copy the coordinates and enter them in the table. But that is a lot of work and it is error prone. I browsed thru all plugins, found the digitizing tools promising but this does not do what I want. I googled this specific question but didn't find a clue.

Is what I want possible at all?

Comment: Perhaps worth taking a look at WFS-T? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Feature_Service

Comment: Thank you @JimJones! Sorry to say that this was not exactly what I wanted. I found the answer after quite some time, and what I want is somewhat possible.

Comment: Nice you found a solution :) thanks for sharing! +2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am rather a noob at gis and qgis so it took me some time before I had the right keywords to search with. And the right keyword for what I want to do apparently is "digitize". What I want is partially possible. Links that helped me are:

- https://www.igismap.com/digitization-in-qgis-exploring-tools-for-digitizing/
- https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41799/adding-shapefiles-to-postgis-database

The gist of it is:

- enable the advance digitizing toolbar: view > toolbars > advanced digitizing toolbar
- create a new shapefile layer: layer > create new shapefile layer. Don't forget the correct fields, in my case the name of the location. Also try to remember where you store the file (it will be a shapefile), you later need that to import the shapefile into postgis
- enable the edit state of the current layer, enable the type of shape you want to import. In my case they were points
- click on each location, a dialog pops up with the attributes you should add
- later on you should import the shapefile, you need the third link for that together with your memory of where you stored that #$@%$& file

Comment: You don't really need to use a shapefile.You can directly edit your PostGIS layer in QGIS. You could also create a temporary table in PostGIS to avoid forgetting where you stored the shapefile...

Comment: I would like to be able to directly edit my PostGis layer. If you make that an answer on how to do that than I'd like to mark that as the correct answer.